# Strange extremely nonspecific error message, malware?

Tags: gnome, 15.04, malware

I use Ubuntu GNOME 15.04 with gnome 3.16, and I got the following error message in a small popup.

> "Warning! System error detected. Would you like to report it?"

While everything was fine and dandy, no problem whatsoever. It's a relatively fresh install with nothing out of the ordinary installed.(essentially gparted, mscorefonts, atom and a few gnome extensions) I reflexively clicked it away so I'm not absolutely sure the wording is 100% exact, but I'm fairly certain. Nautilus, atom and Terminal (with no commands entered yet) were open again, and all functioned correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wouldn't call it malware, it's just [apport](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Apport).

If you just want to get rid of the message and you feel comfortable leaving apport enabled, you can run the following command (remember, apport can sometimes send sensitive info so leaving it enabled is an issue of privacy but it does help the developers take care of bugs and performance issues):

```
sudo rm /var/crash/*
```

Alternatively, you can disable apport by running the following command:

```
sudo sed -i 's/=1/=0/g' /etc/default/apport; cat /etc/default/apport
```

The readout should display:

```
enabled=0
```

on the last line.

Next, you  should probably also disable the apport.service from starting automatically by running the following command:

```
sudo systemctl disable apport.service
```

You can safely ignore the subsequent warnings.

Finally, to stop the apport service:

```
systemctl stop apport.service
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I read after the thing, shouldn't it be disabled by default?  Also, how can I get a more specific description of the error that triggered it? So far it's a good candidate for least helpful error message ever.

Comment: @jetpackneedsrepair Hopefully you didn't delete them yet, run `cat /var/crash/*` to read the crash logs or you can find the individual files in the `/var/crash/` directory using your file manager. Also, I believe apport is only disabled on LTS or "stable" versions of ubuntu like 14.04lts. You are using 15.04 which is more of a short term development release. These releases include stuff that might not always work quite right yet so apport is more of an important factor by contributing data back to developers whenever something doesn't work the way that it should.

Comment: Oh, I thought stable meant it's not a dev/nightly/beta release.I think it's best to turn it off for now and report bugs manually if I find something serious.

Comment: @Jetpackneedsrepair I agree, you can easily sanitize the data manually

Answer (score 4):

That is a normal message. I recommend clicking "`OK`".

While the message is open, you could `xlsclients -al` to list the clients of your X server (`man xlsclients`, of course). See also `man xwininfo`,`man xprop` and (shudder) `man 7 X` to track down which process has that popup open.

Seriously, relax. Just the `apport` crash reporting system. `man -k apport` and `dpkg -L apport` should lead to some interesting reading.